# Functions in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, reusability

I have got many dropdowns in my site and i want to make a reusable function with jquery so i can save a lot of code just by a single function. Can any one help me out in this regard...
For an example

```
<div id="clickMe">
    <div id="showMe">
        <div>I am dropdown item</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

right now i am using it like this way...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#clickMe").click(function(e) {          
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#showMe").toggle();
        $("#clickMe").toggleClass("menu-open");
    });

    $("#showMe").mouseup(function() {
        return false
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        if($(e.target).parent("#clickMe").length==0) {
        $("#clickMe").removeClass("menu-open");
        $("#showMe").hide();
    }
    });
});
```

but now i want to make it more reusable...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: That's an amazingly vague question.  If you want to create a function, then create a function.  I'm confused what your exact goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use html's `class` property to identify all the `div`s with drop-down, and add the event-listener by jQuery's class selector, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //reusable function
  function addMyListener(){ 
    $(".showClass > div").click(function(){
        if($(".showClass").prop("enabled")){
           //do some thing while click drop-down item
        }
    });
  }

  $(function(){
   //call the function while document is ready
   addMyListener();
  });
</script>
<div id="clickMe">
  <!-- add class="showDiv" for all showMe like divs -->
  <div id="showMe" class="showClass">
    <div>I am dropdown item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i wanna make a function like this..function dropdown ( selecter , to_show, activeClass ){
$select = $('selecter');
$show = $('to_show');
$activeClass = $('activeClass');

// default
$select.show();
$show.hide();

//on click event
$select.click(function() {
    $show.toggle();
    $select.toggleClass('$activeClass');
});

//mouse up false on open div
$show.mouseup(function(){
    return false;
});

//Finally hide div if clicked outside
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if(($(e.target).parent('$select').length == 0)){
    $show.hide();
    $select.removeClass('$activeClass');
        }
});
};